How to ensure background tasks are complete in Android?
In my app, I have these two statements:
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    MongoDB.configureRealm()
}

HomeScreen()

It’s crucial for my application that the statement inside LaunchedEffect executes before HomeScreen(), because HomeScreen uses a Realm object that is initialized within LaunchedEffect. However, the application breaks with the following error:
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property realm has not been initialized
at com.example.farmlinkapp1.data.MongoDB.getAllCategories(MongoDB.kt:80)
at com.example.farmlinkapp1.ui.home.HomeViewModel.getAllCategories(HomeViewModel.kt:10)
at com.example.farmlinkapp1.ui.home.HomeScreenKt.HomeScreen(HomeScreen.kt:24)
...

This clearly indicates HomeScreen() begins executing much earlier than configureRealm() finishes, so I tried the following:
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
                MongoDB.configureRealm()
                realmInitialized = true
            }

            if (realmInitialized) {
                HomeScreen(
                    onClick = { categoryId ->
                        navController.navigate(Items(categoryId = categoryId))
                    }
                )
            } else {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }

But the problem persists. Please help!

"because HomeScreen uses a Realm object that is initialized within LaunchedEffect" -- then perhaps you should not be using LaunchedEffect() for this. If this is work that needs to be done each time HomeScreen() is composed, then perhaps use a flow exposed from a viewmodel. If this is work that should be done once per process invocation, you could do the initialization in a repository singleton, perhaps one that is managing your database access.

Hi. I tried to complete the inititalization in an init block inside my singleton, but that didn't help either.

You need to have HomeScreen() be able to react to the completion of that initialization work. For example, HomeScreen() could observe a MutableState or MutableStateFlow that emits the Realm object that HomeScreen() needs.

You clearly dont understand Jetpack Compose you should read more about it. My Suggestion is to initialize Realm in application class

To ensure no thread is running in background, need to check current thread should not contains id equal to 1.
Thread.currentThread().id != 1L

